# How to make an android application with a map of a building, how could i track devices on it?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, tracking, wireless

The app will have a 3d isometric map of the building which should be able to show where you are on it and also where other people are (With their permission of course). I was wondering if there was an accurate way to do this, GPS isn't accurate enough, it doesn't have to give the exact location but it should be able to at least show what room the person is in. I know in most of the rooms in the building there are Wireless routers, would it be at all possible to use them? Thank you for any help.

Comment: code? link? logcat? anything?

Answer (score 1):

I searched for "building wifi location" (without the quotes), and got plenty of relevant hits, including an indoor location service, and an academic paper with the title "Room-Level Wi-Fi Location Tracking".

The problem is more difficult than it looks at first sight. GPS reception is often non-existent inside buildings. WiFi signal strengths are affected by building materials, metal file cabinets and the like. To get accurate results you may need to survey the building, noting the WiFi signature at different locations.

Rooms with routers usually have a stronger signal from their own router than from others, but even that is not guaranteed. There may be more steel between a location in a room and that room's router than between the location and a router in another room.

About ten years ago I did an academic literature survey for this subject, and one interesting possibility I found was a modified Roomba with a post that held a WiFi device at about human hand height. It tracked its location by dead reckoning, and recorded the map of signal strength signatures automatically. I don't know whether there has been further research in robotic indoor wardriving, but I would expect so, given progress in robotics and wifi distribution, as well as interest in location detection.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Yes. With this attitude? Maybe. Try googling "tracking wireless devices"

[This is a nice pointer for you](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/). Try making better questions next time to get better results.